# Keep an input type file content on page refresh or close the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to upload a video files to S3 using the multipart upload method, so I'm trying to implement resumable uploads, the approach that I thought was save the state of the frontend and get it again when the user return to the page, but I'm having problems to store the file in the input on the local store. How can I do that?, is my approach wrong?

Comment: You can't set the value of an `input type="file"` from JavaScript. The best you can do is store the file information in local storage and ask the user to select those files again.

Comment: that sounds very sad